# Show an activity indicator after x seconds, using RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I am currently using RxSwift and the `ActivityIndicator` extension (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxExample/RxExample/Services/ActivityIndicator.swift).

I am trying to achieve showing an activity indicator (spinner) image when an API request takes more than 2 seconds. The RxSwift `ActivityIndicator` is basically a (so-called hot) `Observable<Bool>` that emits `true` when the API calls is made, and `false` when the whole thing is done.

To get the desired behavior, I have played around with many combinations of `throttle`ing, `debounce`ing and such, together with operators like `window` and `pausable`, but I can never get it quite right.

Thoughts?

Comment: I am using ReactiveCocoa, there is a function named `delay(second)` that emit the value after given seconds, I have gone through the readme document in RxSwift, maybe you could have a look of this article: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html

Comment: there is a function named `delaySubscription`, is that what you want?

Comment: I am aware of `delay`, but that would not solve this issue. The problem is that I would not only want to delay the `true` element, but also ignore it entirely if a `false` element has come in before the x seconds at which the spinner should appear.

Comment: What you need to do is to bind `ActivityIndicator`'s property `rx.hidden` (or `rx.animating` if you configured its `hidesWhenStopped`) to a combination of observables for 2-seconds timer and for API request.

Comment: There's quite a nice solution using `switchLatest` here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46730233/64239

Answer (score 0):

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

let activityUntil = 1
// `true` at 0 seconds, `false` at `activityUntil` seconds
let trueUntil = Observable<Int>.timer(0,
                                      period: 1,
                                      scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .map { $0 < activityUntil }
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .shareReplayLatestWhileConnected()

// this is to show you the actual values coming through
_ = trueUntil
    .subscribe { print("raw: \($0)") }

let yourDesiredObservable = trueUntil
    .delaySubscription(2, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)

yourDesiredObservable
    .subscribe { print("still activity?: \($0)") }
```

With `activityUntil = 1`:

> raw: next(true)
>   raw: next(false)
>   still activity?: next(false)

With `activityUntil = 3`:

> raw: next(true)
>   still activity?: next(true)
>   raw: next(false)
>   still activity?: next(false)

As you can see, `yourDesiredObservable` only emits elements after 2 seconds, replaying the last element from before the 2 second mark.