# How can I apply a grace time using RX?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have an `Observable<Bool>` that emits `true` when an operation begins and `false` when it ends.  I'd like to show a message while the operation is in progress, but only if it takes longer than two seconds to begin.  Is there a way I can create an observable that I can bind my message to?  Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you switchMap (a flatMap where when a second item is emitted from the source the subscription to the original observable is unsubscribed and the subscription moves to the next) you could do something like this:

1. booleanObservable
2. .switchMap ( map true to an observable timer of 2 seconds, map false to an empty observable)
3. .onNext show your message    (next won't fire for the empty and a
   quick response would have cut    off the 2 second timer).

Note switchMap is 'switchLatest' in RxSwift.

Could become something like this:

```
booleanObservable
    .map { inProgress -> Observable<Bool> in
        if inProgress {
            return Observable.just(true).delay(time: 2)
        } else {
            return Observable.just(false)
        }
     }
    .switchLatest()
```